# How to re-enable apps using ADB?

Tags: adb, 6.0-marshmallow

I got a samsung galaxy folder 2: https://www.samsung.com/hk_en/smartphones/galaxy-folder2-g165/

It runs Android 6.0.1

Anyways I am not new to ABD and have used it to uninstall system apps on my other phone (Samsung S10) with no problems. So when I got the folder 2 and started removing system apps using pm unistall -k --user 0 as I did with my other phone. Then I decided to remove the contacts app (com.android.contacts) because I installed google contacts.

Well apparently, in doing so that contacts app actually housed the phone app as well. So now I have no phone app on my phone. That's kind of a big deal.

How do I re enable the contacts app using ADB?

My device is not rooted and I don't want to root it. Also I know factory resetting should fix this, but I'd prefer not to do that either. Thanks.

Comment: `system` partition is mounted read-only and nothing can be added/removed without rooting phone.

Comment: you probably meant *pm disable* (not uninstall) so you can just *pm enable* back

Comment: @alecxs it's quite for a while now that, without root, one can use `pm uninstall --user 0 <packageName>` to get rid of bloatware *for the main user* – so OP indeed meant that (the `--user 0` is a good indicator).

Comment: @Izzy ...but *uninstall* doesn't uninstall system apps in that case?

Comment: @alecxs it does make them completely unavailable for the "main user" as if they were completely removed, but the `.apk` file remains on the device (and the app available to other users, if there are any established). You can check that with `dumpsys package`. Hence the `install-existing`, basically telling the system to look for the `/path/to/apk` in `packages.xml`.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there is no way on Android 6 (and even 7) to reinstall a system app uninstalled with `adb shell pm uninstall PACKAGE`.

The command `adb shell cmd package install-existing PACKAGE` can restore the uninstalled package but it has only been introduced with Android 8.0.

On these older android versions, it is safer to use :

```
adb shell am force-stop PACKAGE && pm disable-user PACKAGE && pm clear PACKAGE
```

so you can revert it if necessary :

```
adb shell pm enable PACKAGE
```

**Note:** `PACKAGE` everywhere above means package name of the app.