# Is a rooted phone still required to pass '-k' in ADB's package remove command?

Tags: adb, rooting

I successfully ran `pm uninstall --user 0 packagename` without the -k argument on my phone which isn't rooted, despite the [XDA](https://www.xda-developers.com/uninstall-carrier-oem-bloatware-without-root-access/) article saying it's needed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to re-enable apps using ADB?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/228381/how-to-re-enable-apps-using-adb)

Answer (score 0):

`-k` is option to keep cache + appdata:
*/data/user*/0/<pkgname>*

without that option only the .apk file remains on the device:
*/system/app/<pkgname>/base.apk*

`pm install-existing <pkgname>` will re-enable app with/without appdata depending on `-k`
(explained in section **How to Re-Install**)

Comment: I know, but what confuses me is that the articles I read say that you need to be rooted to be able to leave out the `-k`, but I excluded it on my unrooted phone (just to try) and it worked fine, so I don't know if root's still a requirement.

Comment: So what happens when you exclude `-k`? Does anything other than the app get deleted?