# How to remove uninstalled app?

Tags: uninstallation

I know the title might sound strange, but it does happen on my phone (Samsung). As you can see here, these apps can't be viewed (opened), uninstalled, nor hidden because they don't exist and never be installed on my phone.

[image]

Initially, those apps came from a system app called **Configuration update**. It's been uninstalled by LADB, but why those annoying apps still exist (not really exist, but they just appear like that)?

My best thought to solve this problem is installing those apps and then hide it. But I will never install those apps. This is my least possibility that I could think of. Do you have better idea?

Thanks in advance!

P.s. I had never installed the apps in the first place. Before I uninstalled the *Configuration update*, there were logo of each app (such as bird for twitter, note for tiktok, etc. not those identical android logo) but the apps still gray and when they've been uninstalled, the apps are still gray like that.

Comment: By "LADB", did you mean [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.draco.ladb)? If so, what commands did you use to uninstall the system apps? Is the device rooted?

Comment: @AndrewT. Exactly. Yes that app. My app is unrooted. I saw on youtube. I believe it's  (pm uninstall --user 0 <Package name>). Did I do something wrong?

Comment: I'm sorry I mean, my phone is unrooted. Lol.

Comment: Ah, I see. I have never used that command, but based on [this XDA article](https://www.xda-developers.com/uninstall-carrier-oem-bloatware-without-root-access/) and [this comment](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/228381/how-to-re-enable-apps-using-adb#comment298368_228381), that command only uninstalls the app for the main user, making it unavailable only. It's impossible to uninstall system apps completely without root access. As for hiding them from the app launcher, it may be still a valid question though.